# VB.NET Windows Forms Variables Passing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have got a windows form with a Combobox and two datepickers objects in it. I want upon user selection of the values to pass the variables values to another windows form.

All I've seen is how to do this with showDialog method on an  instance of the class, however this doesn't work for me as the user has to select a user from Combobox and pick the date  range and click on search button.

A quick straight forward help will be appreciated as my time is running close to the deadline.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use delegates to achieve what you want, on selection change in the combobox fire the delegate in which handled in the form you want to pass the value to, and same for the date pickers, on value changed.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show a simple delegate use case or point to a tutorial please.

Comment: A quick way to do this is to use public variables or properties a class or module. Some people consider this bad manners, but it's actually OK if you document what you're doing.

Comment: let me clear first the situation. so you have 2 windows form. the first window form contains the Combobox and datepickers.
so if the user select a range, the result will display in the 2nd windows form. that's what you're saying about passing the values on another form, am I right?

Comment: @kim-jaca , yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

1- creation of public event, singleton approach

```
Public Class EventClass
    Private Sub EventClass()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Invoke(sender as object, value as object)
        RaiseEvent OnValueChange(sender,value) ' be sure OnValueChange is not nothing first
    End Sub
    Public Shared Event OnValueChange(sender as object,value as object)
End Class
```

2- raising the event, in the form that containing the combobox and datepicker

- Handle the event of the combo on selected index changed

inside the event of combo raise the event as

```
EventClass.Invoke(ComboBox1,ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
```

and in the case of DateTimePicker use

```
EventClass.Invoke(DateTimePicker1,DateTimePicker.Date)
```

3- in the form that you want to pass the values to

```
public sub EventClass_OnValueChange(sender as object, value as object) handles EventClass.OnValueChange
 ' do your code here but be sure that this form was created before the form that contains the invoke or it will not be fired
end sub
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Hadi, this won't help because the form using the event is created later not before the form that contains the invoke. thanks for your support but this is as good as using the showDialog method too.